# Bar plot with broken y-axis and log x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I am looking to present a variable as a bar plot with the caveat that the groups I am trying to plot (the size of an object) vary over several orders of magnitude. The other complication of the data is that the variable y also varies over several orders of magnitude when positive as well as having negative values. I usually think in pictures so I have sketched something along the lines that I am looking for below (the colour would simply be a function of the distance from zero, i.e. white zero, dark blue very negative, dark red very positive etc):
[image: Plot plan]

Here is a real case of the data if required:

```
x <- c(1.100e-08, 1.200e-08, 1.300e-08, 1.400e-08, 1.600e-08, 1.700e-08, 1.900e-08, 2.100e-08, 2.300e-08, 2.600e-08, 3.100e-08, 3.500e-08, 4.200e-08, 4.700e-08, 5.200e-08, 5.800e-08, 6.400e-08, 7.100e-08, 7.900e-08, 8.800e-08, 9.800e-08, 1.100e-07, 1.230e-07, 1.380e-07, 1.550e-07, 1.760e-07, 3.250e-07, 3.750e-07, 4.250e-07, 4.750e-07, 5.400e-07, 6.150e-07, 6.750e-07, 7.500e-07, 9.000e-07, 1.150e-06, 1.450e-06, 1.800e-06, 2.250e-06, 2.750e-06, 3.250e-06, 3.750e-06, 4.500e-06, 5.750e-06, 7.000e-06, 8.000e-06, 9.250e-06, 1.125e-05, 1.375e-05, 1.625e-05, 1.875e-05, 2.250e-05, 2.750e-05, 3.100e-05)

y <-c(1.592140e+01, -1.493541e+01, -6.255603e+00, -2.191637e+00, -1.274086e+00, -1.343391e+00, -8.869018e-01, -7.717447e-01, -6.140710e-01, -5.637220e-01, -5.404424e-01, -3.473077e-01, -2.279666e-01, -1.945254e-01, -2.485636e-01, -2.363181e-01, -2.197054e-01, -2.119314e-01, -1.897220e-01, -1.656779e-01, -1.478176e-01, -1.364191e-01, -1.297830e-01, -1.408082e-01, -1.514742e-01, -1.311300e-01, -1.358422e-01, -2.718636e+00, -2.231532e+00, -3.479395e+00, -3.572720e+00, -2.297957e+00, -3.265428e+00, -5.449620e+00, -7.741435e+00, -1.172256e+01,  9.368365e+00,  1.078983e+02,  9.542029e+01,  1.484089e+02,  2.293383e+02,  3.678836e+02, 7.965286e+02,  1.349151e+03,  1.577808e+04,  4.554271e+05,  1.821730e+06,  8.092310e+04,  1.015619e+06, 2.113788e+06,  5.208331e+06,  4.534863e+06,  8.086026e+06,  1.577413e+07)
```

I could also plot this as a scatterplot with broken axis but I am currently playing with the a nice approach to display such data- important for me is highlighting at the approximate value of x that y changes sign as well as the variability and magnitude of both the positive and negative values. Any tips and advice you have plotting such data would be great.

**Edit based upon comments**

I realise that on my graph x and y are the wrong way around, apologies for that. Parameter x should indeed be on the x-axis and parameter y on the y-axis.
Taking on board your suggestions I would be better to plot this data as a scatterplot. Accepting that I still need to break my axis at a relevant value of y (not x as shown in the figure) and have a log scale above this value and linear scale below. Somewhere below the smallest "positive" value of y seems sensible for this break. Can this be done using base r?

I guess something like [this](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22832) but with the split on the y-axis rather than the x-axis and in r of course.

Comment: Thank you for the data. Can you please also supply what code you have already written, even if broken.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do : x and y seem inverted in your figure, you want a barplot but your data corresponds to a scatterplot...

Comment: The plot you want to make is very confusing! The 0 on the linear scale corresponds to a 1 on the log scale. A barchart helps to compare magnitudes. Having differents scales removes this advantage.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post to reflect your comments.

Comment: I have read the question a couple of times and my reaction is that if it's this hard to explain (and implement), it's probably better to do it another way.

Comment: if you're still intressed in it? to mix a log scale and a linar scale in one plot seems very confusing for the person who should understand your message...but if you really like to do it's possible with a empty plot, filled with rects and add the axis after manually - but it is a little complicated. so give a sign if its still nessesary to think about this ;)